# Uploading blob into Azure container

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have such a code statement:

```
if ($_POST) {

//specify folder for file upload
$folder = dirname($_POST['file']); 

//specify redirect URL
$redirect = "upload.php?success";

//upload the file
//


// Create blob REST proxy.
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);


$content = $folder;
$blob_name = $_POST['name'];

try {
    //Upload blob
    $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("mis112", $blob_name, $content);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here: 
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
//
//do whatever else needs to be done (insert information into database, etc...)

//redirect user
header('Location: '.$redirect); die;
}
//

?>
```

I want to upload a blob into my container called "mis112".

With this code, it worket at first, and I saw my blob in the container "mis112".

But at the 2nd time, even I got succeed message after uploading, I couldn't see my blob in azure container.

What's wrong with it?

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try by removing `header('Location: '.$redirect); die;` line of code? It could be possible that the 2nd time upload is throwing an error but because you're redirecting the user to another page, you are not seeing the error.

Comment: Actually Gaurav, I found the problem. I cannot hold the directory name by getting from html form. Now I'm trying to manage it. Can you say something about this?

Comment: I mean, probably at first it run, but just recorded the name of directory as a file, not recorded the file.